# Display div value that matches with attribute from other div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two `divs` created from PHP loop:

```
<div class="sku">
  <span class="sku-value" data-id="150">1000</span>
  <span class="sku-value" data-id="151">2000</span>
  <span class="sku-value" data-id="152">3000</span>
</div>

<div class="size-values">
  <span class="size-value" data-id="150">M</span>
  <span class="size-value" data-id="151">L</span>
  <span class="size-value" data-id="152">XL</span>
</div>
```

These `divs` has parent div called attributes.

`sku-value` and size-value have something in common: data-id attribute.

With CSS I'm manipulating the `sku-value` spans:

```
.sku-value {
  display:none;
} 

.sku-value.active {
   display:inline-block;
 }
```

With jQuery I'm displaying only the first size-value:

```
$('.sku-value:first').addClass('active');
```

So in this case when the page is loaded only this sku-value will be visible:

```
<span class="sku-value" data-id="150">1000</span>
```

With my code bellow I can successfully change the active class of each clicked size-value but how can I change the displayed sku-value that matches the data-id value?

For example: if a user click on one of size-value that has data-id 152, how can I display the `sku-value` that has data-id 152 and hide the current visible `sku-value`?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sku-value:first').addClass('active');

    $('.attributes').find('.size-value').on('click', function(){

      if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $this.closest('.size-values').find('.size-value').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
      }

    });
  });
```

Comment: Read the attribute, then use it to select the other element. Reading an attribute is trivial, and using it in a selector works like `$(\`.size-values [data-id="${id}"]\`)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you require you can retrieve the `data-id` of the clicked element, then use `filter()` to retrieve all elements by that `data` attribute before setting the `active` class on them.

Here's an example showing how to do that, and also some tweaks to the logic to make it more succinct:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $skuAttributes = $('.sku-value');
  let $sizeAttributes = $('.size-value');
  let $allAttributes = $skuAttributes.add($sizeAttributes);
  
  // set default state on page load
  $skuAttributes.first().addClass('active');
  $sizeAttributes.first().addClass('active');

  // on click of a size attribute, set active class on all relevant elements
  $sizeAttributes.on('click', function() {
    $sizeAttributes.removeClass('active');
    
    let dataId = $(this).data('id'); 
    $allAttributes.removeClass('active').filter((i, el) => el.dataset.id == dataId).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
div { font-size: 1.3em; }
.sku-value { display: none; }
.sku-value.active { display: inline-block; }
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="attributes">
  <div class="sku">
    <span class="sku-value" data-id="150">1000</span>
    <span class="sku-value" data-id="151">2000</span>
    <span class="sku-value" data-id="152">3000</span>
  </div>

  <div class="size-values">
    <span class="size-value" data-id="150">M</span>
    <span class="size-value" data-id="151">L</span>
    <span class="size-value" data-id="152">XL</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional-style, vanilla-flavored solution I came up with. Several helper functions share the heavy lifting, so the main listener function stays simple and clean.

Instead of the `active` class, this uses a `hidden` class that can apply to `sku` spans as well as `size` spans.

(I'm late to the party because I wrote this script while I was offline today.)

```js
const
  // Collects DOM elements as arrays
  sizes = [...document.getElementsByClassName("size-value")],
  skus  = [...document.getElementsByClassName("sku-value")],
  spans = [...sizes, ...skus],

  // Defines helper functions
  isHidden = (_this) => _this.classList.contains("hidden"),
  isActive = (_this) => sizes.every((size) => isHidden(size) || size === _this),
  showAll = (_these) => _these.forEach((_this) => _this.classList.remove("hidden")),
  hideAll = (_these) => _these.forEach((_this) => _this.classList.add("hidden")),
  filterByDataId = (_these, id) => _these.filter(_this => _this.dataset.id === id);

// Invokes listener when user clicks a size
sizes.forEach(size => size.addEventListener("click", hideAndShow));

// Defines listener
function hideAndShow({target}){ // Destructures click event
  if(isActive(target)){
    showAll(spans);
  }
  else{
    hideAll(spans);
    showAll(filterByDataId(spans, target.dataset.id));
  }
}
```

```css
div { margin: 1em 0; }
span { padding: 0.1em 0.3em; border: 1px solid grey; }
.hidden{ display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="sku">
    <span class="sku-value" data-id="150">1000</span>
    <span class="sku-value hidden" data-id="151">2000</span>
    <span class="sku-value hidden" data-id="152">3000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="size-values">
    <span class="size-value" data-id="150">Medium</span>
    <span class="size-value" data-id="151">Large</span>
    <span class="size-value" data-id="152">Xtra Large</span>
  </div>
```